# How to navigate (redirect) a user to a page after registering the user - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to redirect a user to a page that informs the user to check his email for verification immediately after registration. I am trying to use **Navigate** from react-router-dom but the return statement was not being executed. Below is my code

**API call**

```
import { ToastNotification } from "../components/ToastNotification";
import axiosInstance from "../utils/axiosInstance";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

export const userRegister = async (email, password, regd_as) => {
  const body = JSON.stringify({ email, password, regd_as });

  try {
    const response = await axiosInstance.post(`/account/signup/`, body);
    if (response.status === 201) {
      ToastNotification("Account has been created successfully.", "success");
      return <Navigate to="/verify-email" />;  //this is not being executed
    }
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      if (
        error.response.status === 400 &&
        error.response.data.message === "User Exists"
      ) {
        ToastNotification("Account already exists.", "error");
      } else {
        ToastNotification(
          "We are facing some problems. Please try registering later.",
          "error"
        );
      }
    } else if (error.request) {
      ToastNotification(
        "We are facing some problems. Please try registering some time later."
      );
    }
  }
};
```

**component calling the API**

```
  const formDataSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (password !== conPassword) {
      ToastNotification(
        "Password and Confirm Password did not match.",
        "error"
      );
    } else {
      if (regd_as === "") {
        ToastNotification(`"Registered As" cannot be blank`, "info");
      } else {
        userRegister(email, password, regd_as);
      }
    }
  };
```

what should I do to redirect the user immediately after registering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return JSX from a callback like this and expect it to be rendered and affect any change. In other words, the `Navigate` component isn't actually rendered into the DOM to do anything.

Use the `useNavigate` hook to access a `navigate` function as part of a resolved Promise from the `userRegister` function. Pass the `navigate` function to the handler.

Example:

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const navigate = useNavigate();

...

const formDataSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (password !== conPassword) {
    ToastNotification(
      "Password and Confirm Password did not match.",
      "error"
    );
  } else {
    if (regd_as === "") {
      ToastNotification(`"Registered As" cannot be blank`, "info");
    } else {
      userRegister(email, password, regd_as, navigate); // <-- pass navigate function
    }
  }
};
```

...

```
import { ToastNotification } from "../components/ToastNotification";
import axiosInstance from "../utils/axiosInstance";

export const userRegister = async (email, password, regd_as, navigate) => {
  const body = JSON.stringify({ email, password, regd_as });

  try {
    const response = await axiosInstance.post(`/account/signup/`, body);
    if (response.status === 201) {
      ToastNotification("Account has been created successfully.", "success");
      return navigate("/verify-email" { replace: true }); // <-- issue imperative redirect
    }
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      if (
        error.response.status === 400 &&
        error.response.data.message === "User Exists"
      ) {
        ToastNotification("Account already exists.", "error");
      } else {
        ToastNotification(
          "We are facing some problems. Please try registering later.",
          "error"
        );
      }
    } else if (error.request) {
      ToastNotification(
        "We are facing some problems. Please try registering some time later."
      );
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the return should be wrapped with brackets like this

```
 return(
   <>
 <Navigate to="/verify-email" />
   </>
)
```

Here's more info https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/return-variable-in-render-function-in-react

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).